# Best way to represent a group of information

Tags: usability, website-design, web, ux-integration

What is the best way to represent the group of information considering UX and UI, what styles should I used ?

See the image attached here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timeline to show this info,it would be more intuitive